# Why is my SimpleOnGestureListener not functioning?

Tags: android, gesture, swipe, swipe-gesture, onfling

I'm using my own GestureDetector class to detect a left|right onFling event.  Everything I see looks good in my code but nothing happens...?

I need the added functionality beyond my toggle button that opens|closes a navigation view in my fragments. The toggle calls on a method in my AnimationLayout class as follows:

```
public void toggleSidebar()
{
if (mContent.getAnimation() != null)
{
return;
}

if (mOpened)
{
/* opened, make close animation */
mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -mSidebarWidth, 0, 0);
mAnimation.setAnimationListener(mCloseListener);
} else
{
/* not opened, make open animation */
mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, mSidebarWidth, 0, 0);
mAnimation.setAnimationListener(mOpenListener);
}
mAnimation.setDuration(DURATION);
mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
mAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
mContent.startAnimation(mAnimation);
}
```

and...

```
public void openSidebar()
    {
    if (!mOpened)
    {
    toggleSidebar();
    }
    }

    public void closeSidebar()
    {
    if (mOpened)
    {
    toggleSidebar();
    }
    }
```

Within my Main Activity the onFling() calls on the toggle sub:

```
public static AnimationLayout mLayout;

    // these constants are used for onFling
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mLayout = (AnimationLayout) findViewById(R.id.animation_layout);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this.getApplicationContext(), new MyGestureDetector());
        // Set the touch listener for the main view to be our custom gesture
        // listener
        mLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
      class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "right_left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("MyGestureDetector", "R2L!");
                mLayout.closeSidebar();
                // left to right swipe
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "left_right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("MyGestureDetector", "L2R!");
                mLayout.openSidebar();
            }

            return false;
        }

        // Return true from onDown for the onFling event to register
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This Button works fine:

```
...
case R.id.navToggleBtn : {
                mLayout.toggleSidebar();
            }
...
```

Comment: Can you verify that your `TouchListener` is even receiving all the events to have them forwarded on?  If your layout contains children that are also touchable, they may be stealing the events from their parent (your layout).

Comment: I think you may be correct.  I'll put the function on a child layout and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give credit to @Devunwired as he suggested above:

> If layout contains children that are also touchable, they may be
>   stealing the events from their parent (your layout).

So I added:

```
View swipeView = (View) findViewById(R.id.animation_layout_content);
swipeView .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {...});
```

Which works wonderfully now.

Comment: Another thing you may look at it `onInterceptTouchEvent()` which is the method designed to allow `ViewGroups` to take touches from their children when they need to handle them for gestures like swipe.

Answer (score 1):

I think one reason is that Gesture work on  `onFling` that condition not satisfied in u r code 
i have implemented one OntouchListener try this

```
yourView.setOnTouchListner(onThumbTouch );




    OnTouchListener onThumbTouch = new OnTouchListener()
        {
            float previouspoint = 0 ;
            float startPoint=0;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {   
                switch(v.getId())
                {
                case R.id.tvDetailsalaujairiyat: // Give your R.id.sample ...
                {
                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    {          
                        startPoint=event.getX();
                        System.out.println("Action down,..."+event.getX());
                    }
                    break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    {       

                    }break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    {                           

                        previouspoint=event.getX();
                        if(previouspoint > startPoint){
                            //Right side swape

                        }else{
                        // Left side swape
                        }

                    }break;

                    }
                    break;
                }
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
```